# Convert text file into dictionary with line number as value

Tags: python, file, dictionary, text

I have to convert text file into dictionary and use line number as a value for dictionary.

**Example text file 'test.txt':**

aaaa 4.5

bbbb

3 cccc dddd

**Output** I need to get is dictionary looking like this:

{'aaa':1 , 4.5:1, 'bbbb':2, 3:3, 'cccc':3, 'dddd':3}

Comment: Do you have some code to show? Or you need someone do the code for you?

Comment: I need someone to do the code for me... :(

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place for people to make code for you. It helps with problems within your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work as in the above answer the last string will contain `\n`

```
val = 1
dic = {}
with open("a.txt") as a:
    for line in a:
        a = line.split(" ")
        for ech in a:
            dic[ech.replace("\n","")] = val
        val += 1

print(dic)
```

Comment: If it worked for you then please accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple way to do it:

```
filename = "C:/Users/henri/Downloads/test.txt"    # your own filename
f = open(filename, 'r')                           # open file reader
lis = f.readlines()                               # read all lines into a list
dic = {}                                          # make empty dictionary

for i,line in enumerate(lis):                     # loop through lines
    line = line.rstrip("\n")                      # remove trailing newline
    parts = line.split()                          # split into all parts of line

    for a in parts:                               # loop thourhg all the parts of the line
        dic[line] = i+1                           # add to dictionary

print(dic)
```

edit: didnt see that you wanted to split the lines at whitespaces, added it...

Answer (score -1):

```py
dct = {}
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        for token in line.split():
            dct[token] = index+1

print(dct)
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and how it does it.